# vSeed Required or vFixedSeed Enough?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, seed

Im creating a new alt coin so I can understand the technology and have most of my changes done and I am trying to understand the vSeed and VFixedSeed logic. I don't have a DNS that will serve up a bunch of IP's since it will be jsut a static IP's of my 2 VM's I have created to simulate nodes. Can I just generate ips in the chainparamsseeds.h file for main and test nets or will my service fail without actual vSeed values?

Comment: I guess they are used in this object pnSeed6_main which gets ref by vFixedSeeds

Comment: When running the application I get 0 connections when using just vFixedSeeds I dont see where these get used in any of the networking so what are they even used for are they depricated?